# Setting process priority in Windows Task Manager on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, task-manager, threads, priority

I am trying to change the base priority to "Above Normal" for a process using Task Manager in Windows Server 2008 R2, but the value keeps changing back to "Normal" in the Base Priority column (and also inside the context menu).

It's only shown as "Above Normal" for several seconds, and then switches back to "Normal". I am logged in as the Administrator, and the application is a console app which I started by double clicking it.

Does this mean:

1) I am unable to set the priority for some reason? or

2) Windows Server 2008 R2 Task Manager doesn't show the actual base priority?

Comment: try ProcessExplorer instead

Comment: It is possible that the process is setting it's own priority.

Comment: @LMiller7: it's a console app compiled by myself in Visual C++. Nothing inside which would change its priority.

Comment: older server included a optimization service, called Windows System Resource Manager, maybe it changes values back. look if this is enabled and configured to set priority back to normal